# How to fix Resource not Found with getResourceAsStream

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I am following this guide to use the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java) on my applicaton, I reused the same code on the example, but for some reason I am having the following error. How do I get this json file?

I have tried changing the position of the file, but nothing has worked out.

**This is the error im getting:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resource not found: /credentials.json
    at com.albot.focus.Utils.GoogleCalendarAPI.getCredentials(GoogleCalendarAPI.java:51)
    at com.albot.focus.Utils.GoogleCalendarAPI.main(GoogleCalendarAPI.java:68)
```

I expect to retrieve the events from the user on the Google Calendar API.

Comment: Did you completed the step 2? it asks to download credentials.json

Comment: Yes, I did and added on the app/src/main/res folder...

Comment: Can you show the output of `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`

Answer (score 0):

Directory `resources` is called `res` on Android - so that quick-start is obviously not an Android example and this is generally the wrong authentication flow for a mobile end-device. If this is Android, there is nothing to "fix" and you probably shouldn't be using service account credentials at all, but Google API with the *current* user's identity, because AAPT2 will process all XML except `res/raw`.

Use dependencies alike these, in order not to authenticate with a service account:

```
dependencies {

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client
    implementation "com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.25.0"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client-android
    implementation "com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.25.0"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client-jackson2
    implementation "com.google.api-client:google-api-client-jackson2:1.25.0"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-calendar
    implementation "com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev378-1.25.0"    
}
```

typical [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ...

Comment: Yes i already did that, but still it says it doesnt find the json.

Comment: @Alson added a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you placed your credentials.json in Project mode into 'app' folder?

[image]